# Problem joining char* to filesystem::path.filename() or char[260]

Tags: c++

I Know similar questions have been asked before but none of them Helped in my case.

Basically I want `dstPath` = %AppData% + "CURRENT EXE NAME"

but problem is with different string types and string concantation

**SIMPLIFIED CODE :-**

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <filesystem>

#include <Shlwapi.h>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    TCHAR selfPath[MAX_PATH];
    TCHAR dstPath[MAX_PATH];
    
    if (GetModuleFileName(NULL, selfPath, MAX_PATH) == 0)       // Getting exe File Location
        printf("Error : %ul\n", GetLastError());
    
    filesystem::path p(selfPath);
    
    dstPath = strcat(getenv("APPDATA"), p.filename().string().c_str());     // Here Comes The Error
    
    printf("Src : %s\n", selfPath);
    printf("Dst : %s\n", dstPath);
    
    return 0;
}
```

**COMPILER COMMAND :-**

`g++ -Os -s -o ./builds/gcc-rat-x64.exe ./source/rat.cpp -std=c++17 -m64 -lshlwapi`

**COMPILER ERROR :-**

```cpp
error: incompatible types in assignment of 'char*' to 'TCHAR [260]' {aka 'char [260]'}
   80 |  dstPath = strcat(getenv("APPDATA"), p.filename().string().c_str());
```

Comment: You're not allowed to modify the string returned by [`std::getenv`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv). Attempting to do so, like you do with the `strcat` call, leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: As for the error itself, you can't assign to an array, only copy to it. If you're programming in C++, why don't you use `std::filesystem::path` for *all* paths? And `std::string` for *all* strings?

Comment: @Some programmer dude can't use `std::string` because <Windows.h> functions don't accept it. This code is just a sample out of full code.

Comment: `std::string selfPath(MAX_PATH, 0); GetModuleFileNameA(NULL, selfPath.data(), selfPath.length());` Also try to use `std::cout` instead of `printf`. I recommend [a decent book or two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to help you learn C++ better.

Comment: I use `<stdio.h>` beacuse it produces much smaller executable after compiling than `<iostream>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot assign to arrays. You should use [`strcpy()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html) to copy C-style strings.

```
strcpy(dstPath, getenv("APPDATA"));
strcat(dstPath, p.filename().string().c_str());
```

Or the concatination can be done in one line via [`snprintf()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html):

```
snprintf(dstPath, sizeof(dstPath), "%s%s", getenv("APPDATA"), p.filename().string().c_str());
```

Finally, `TCHAR` and `GetModuleFileName` can refer to UNICODE version of the API, according to the compilation option. Using ANSI version (`char` and `GetModuleFileNameA`) explicitly is safer to work with `std::string` and other APIs that require strings consists of `char`.

Comment: Note that these solutions assume `getenv("APPDATA")` always outputs a trailing ```\``` character, which is not guaranteed. `PathCombine()` or related Win32 API would be better. `std::filesystem::path::operator/=` would be even better.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use strcat to concatenate two strings and store the result in another one, but it does not work that way. The call `strcat (str1, str2)` adds the content of `str2` at the end of `str1`. It also returns a pointer to `str1` but I don't normally use it.

What you are trying to do should be done in three steps:

- Make sure that `dstPath` contains an empty string
- Concatenate to `dstPath` the value of the environment variable APPDATA
- Concatenate to `dstPath` the value of filename

Something like this:

```
dstPath[0] = '\0';
strcat(dstPath, getenv("APPDATA"));
strcat(dstPath, p.filename().string().c_str());
```

You should also add checks not to overflow `dstPath`...

Comment: In fact, the answer by @MikeCAT is probably better. I wanted to stick to `strcat` but in the real world you would substitute the first two steps for `strcpy` as he suggests.

Comment: I still get the same error with your solution

Comment: in second line you should use strcpy() instead of strcat() for it to work

Comment: and wouldn't the null terminator get in the beginning this way ?

Comment: No, the null terminator at the beginning converts `dstPath` into an empty string at first, and `strcat` takes care of moving the terminator to the end of the string after concatenating each new string. It's strange that you get the same error, I just tried it just in case and it works perfectly for me. I assume that you have removed the `dstPath = ` part before the `strcat`, didn't you?

Comment: it was saying dstPath not defined so i changed it to `TCHAR dstPath[MAX_PATH]; dstPath = '\0'`, then i get the same old error as mentioned in question.

Comment: @TanishqBanyal you can't assign a single `TCHAR` to a `TCHAR[]` array like that.  You meant to use `dstPath[0] = _T('\0');` instead to set the 1st `TCHAR` in the array.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you are mixing `TCHAR` and `char` APIs in a way you should not be.  You really should not be using `TCHAR` at all in modern code.  But, if you are going to use `TCHAR`, then at least use `TCHAR`- based functions/macros, like `_tprintf()` instead of `printf()`, `_tcscat()` instead of `strcat()`, etc.

The compiler error is because you are trying to assign the `char*` pointer returned by `strcat()` to your `dstPath` `TCHAR[]` array.  You can't assign a pointer to an array like that.  You should `strcpy()` the result of `getenv()` into `dstPath` first, and then `strcat()` your filename onto the end of it, eg:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <filesystem>

#include <Windows.h>
#include <Shlwapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

TCHAR* _tgetenv(const TCHAR *varname)
{
    #ifdef _UNICODE
    return _wgetenv(varname);
    #else
    return getenv(varname);
    #endif
}

std::basic_string<TCHAR> path2TStr(const std::filesystem::path &p)
{
    #ifdef _UNICODE
    return p.wstring();
    #else
    return p.string();
    #endif
}

int main()
{
    TCHAR selfPath[MAX_PATH];
    TCHAR dstPath[MAX_PATH];
    
    if (GetModuleFileName(NULL, selfPath, MAX_PATH) == 0)       // Getting exe File Location
    {
        printf("Error : %ul\n", GetLastError());
        return 0;
    }

    std::filesystem::path p(selfPath);
    
    _tcscpy(dstPath, _tgetenv(_T("APPDATA")));
    _tcscat(dstPath, path2TStr(p.filename()).c_str());
    
    _tprintf(_T("Src : %s\n"), selfPath);
    _tprintf(_T("Dst : %s\n"), dstPath);
    
    return 0;
}
```

However, you really should be using [`SHGetFolderPath(CSIDL_APPDATA)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetfolderpathw) or [`SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_RoamingAppData)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath) instead of using `getenv("APPDATA")`.

And since you are using the `<filesystem>` library anyway, you really should just use `std::filesystem::path` for all of your path handling.  It has [`operator/=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/append) and [`operator/`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/operator_slash) to concatenate path segments, and an [`operator<<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/operator_ltltgtgt) for printing paths to a `std::ostream`, like `std::cout`. Don't use `strcat()` for concatenating path segments, it won't handle directory separators correctly, at least.

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <filesystem>
#include <stdexcept>

#include <Windows.h>
#include <Shlobj.h>

std::filesystem::path getSelfPath()
{
    WCHAR wPath[MAX_PATH] = {};
    
    if (!GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, wPath, MAX_PATH))       // Getting exe File Location
    {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        throw std::runtime_error("Error : " << std::to_string(err));
    }

    return wPath;
}

std::filesystem::path getAppDataPath()
{
    WCHAR wPath[MAX_PATH] = {};
    
    HRESULT hRes = SHGetFolderPathW(NULL, CSIDL_APPDATA, NULL, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, wPath);       // Getting APPDATA Folder Location
    if (hRes != S_OK)
        throw std::runtime_error("Error : " << std::to_string(hRes));

    return wPath;
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        auto selfPath = getSelfPath();
        auto dstPath = getAppDataPath() / selfPath.filename();
    
        std::cout << "Src : " << selfPath << "\n";
        std::cout << "Dst : " << dstPath << "\n";
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << "\n";
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yes i have already switched to filesystem for this problem(and i was thinking of adding a answer here), still thanks.